# Upgraded to Capacitor 3 now my tests are broken

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am currently running Angular 12 and capacitor 2 was working fine with it. Now that I upgraded to version 3 my tests are broken throwing ChunkErrors. Like  `Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk node_modules_capacitor_toast_dist_esm_web_js failed.` It seems all my issues arise from the new plugin implementation. I appreciate any insights you might have. Thank you!

Has anyone had this issue?

This is my karma.config.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
 basePath: '',
 frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
 plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
  require('karma-junit-reporter'),
  require('karma-spec-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage'),
  require('karma-sonarqube-reporter'),
  require('ts-loader')
],

client: {
  // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
  clearContext: false,
  jasmine: {
    random: false
  }
},
reporters: ['progress', 'coverage', 'junit', 'spec', 'sonarqube'],

mime: { 'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'] },
junitReporter: {
  outputDir: './test-results',
  outputFile: 'junit-unit-test-results.xml',
  useBrowserName: false
},

coverageReporter: {
  // specify a common output directory
  dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
  reports: ['cobertura', 'html', 'lcov', 'text'],
  reporters: [
    // reporters not supporting the `file` property
    { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
    { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' },
    // reporters supporting the `file` property, use `subdir` to directly
    // output them in the `dir` directory
    { type: 'cobertura', subdir: '.', file: 'cobertura.txt' }
  ],
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
  combineBrowserReports: true,
  skipFilesWithNoCoverage: true,
  includeAllSources: true,
  thresholds: {
    // set to `true` to not fail the test command when thresholds are not met
    emitWarning: false,
    // thresholds for all files
    global: {
      statements: 0,
      lines: 45,
      branches: 0,
      functions: 0
    },
    // thresholds per file
    each: {
      statements: 0,
      lines: 0,
      branches: 0,
      functions: 0
    }
  }
},

port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['CustomChromeHeadless'],
browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
browserDisconnectTimeout: 60000,
browserDisconnectTolerance: 2,
browserSocketTimeout: 80000,
captureTimeout: 180000,
sonarqubeReporter: {
  basePath: 'src/app',
  filePattern: '**/*spec.ts',
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  outputFolder: 'test-results',
  legacyMode: false,
  reportName: () => {
    const metadata_SonarUnit = ['sonar-unit-test-results'];
    return metadata_SonarUnit.concat('xml').join('.');
  }
},
singleRun: true,
restartOnFileChange: false,
customLaunchers: {
  CustomChromeHeadless: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: [
      '--headless',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-translate',
      '--disable-extensions',
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0',
      '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    ],
    debug: true
    }
   }
 });
};
```

Comment: Hi, I think you using capacitor toast in any file and you know import style changed in v3. Maybe you should check all capacitor imports.

Comment: @EmreAkbaki thank you! I was able to solve the issue by following what is defined here: https://github.com/ionic-team/cap-plugin-mock-jasmine

Answer (score 1):

Followed the instructions here: https://github.com/ionic-team/cap-plugin-mock-jasmine